# Generate unique numbers RANDOM function OS X

Tags: osx, array, random

I am creating a random generator based from a number array list. However, I would like it to be unique so that random number cannot be used again. I have tried creating a ***'USED'*** array list which will store the currently random generated number and then after generate another random then loop through the ***'USED'*** array list and check if it has already been used. If it has then keep generating until there is number that hasn't been used.

Here is what I have so far.

**generate.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

USED[0]=""
USED[1]=""
USED[2]=""
USED[3]=""
USED[4]=""
USED[5]=""
USED[6]=""
USED[7]=""
USED[8]=""
USED[9]=""

NUMBER[0]="1"
NUMBER[1]="2"
NUMBER[2]="3"
NUMBER[3]="4"
NUMBER[4]="5"
NUMBER[5]="6"
NUMBER[6]="7"
NUMBER[7]="8"
NUMBER[8]="9"
NUMBER[9]="0"

for i in "${NUMBER[@]}"; do
 let RANDNUMBER=$RANDOM%10
 for j in "${USED[@]}"; do
  if [ $j -eq $RANDOMNUMBER ]; then
   let RANDNUMBER=$RANDOM%10
  else
   echo ${NUMBER[$RANDNUMBER]} >> generated.txt
  fi
 done
done
```

When I run the script there are no errors, however there is nothing being outputted to the ***generated.txt*** file, it is blank.

Is there anything that I am missing? I hope you guys can help :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Could you also explain what the `%10` in `RANDNUMBER=$RANDOM%10` is supposed to do? Are you trying to do modulus 10? Do you need a specific type of number?

Comment: The `%10` will generate a RANDOM number between 0-9. Yes, I need a specific number since the range of the `NUMBERS` array is between 0-9.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to shuffle a list is to loop over the elements and *swap* with another element at random.

```
#! /bin/bash -
list=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0)
random_list=("${list[@]}")
n=${#random_list[@]}
for ((i = 0; i < n; i++)); do
  (( r = RANDOM % n ))
  tmp=${random_list[i]}
  random_list[i]=${random_list[r]}
  random_list[r]=$tmp
done
printf '%s\n' "${random_list[@]}" > generated.txt
```

Having said that, FreeBSD `sort` has a `-R` option to sort randomly, I'd be surprised if OS/X sort didn't, so you should be able to do (assuming array elements don't contain newline characters):

```
printf '%s\n' "${list[@]}" | sort -R > generated.txt
```

Comment: Hi, I have tested your answer and it is randomising the list however I only wanted those numbers in the list to displayed only once. Thanks

Comment: @RyanHawdon, sorry, there was a typo. It should be fixed now.

Comment: Stéphane Chazelas Thank you so much !! It is working perfectly. You're a life saver :)

Answer (score 1):

Two typos:

`[ $j -eq $RANDOMNUMBER ]` should be `[[ $j -eq $RANDNUMBER ]]`

It seems to work after making the corrections.